# Connect to MS SQL on (Linux)Centos with Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux, codeigniter

I like to connect an MS SQL database on (Linux)Centos with Codeigniter. Just installed the Centos Linux. Apache/ftp works.

But know i want to connect to an internal SQL server in my Linux machine trough Codeigniter.
I already installed with Yum mssql-php but when i trying to connect in Codeigniter it says "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.".

My question is what i need to do on my Centos machine to connect my Codeigniter PHP with an internal SQL 2008 database?

My Codeigniter setting are:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '***\***,1433';
$db['default']['username'] = '***';
$db['default']['password'] = '***';
$db['default']['database'] = '**';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql'; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

On an XAMPP Windows machine this setup works well bu using sqlsrv. But that is only
supported on a Windows machine..

-- Edit --

Screen of my PHPinfo shows this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently working for my by installing mssql at the Linux machine. Codeigniter has the following configuration:

```
$db['sql']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';

$db['sql']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['sql']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['sql']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['sql']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['sql']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['sql']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['sql']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['sql']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['sql']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['sql']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**PHP configuration:**
[image]

**FreetDs config on Linux server**

It is important to configure the connection on the Linux machine in the FreetDS config. After that you will see in the phpinfo that there is an Active connection an Codeigniter can connect with the SQL database.

[image]

Comment: if you give $db['sql']['db_debug'] = FALSE; means , Are you got database table values?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **php-mssql** extension on your linux machine.

Step 1: *Install needed respositories*

Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Remi Dependency on CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
```

---

Step 2: *Install the extension*

```
yum --enablerepo=remi php-mssql
```

---

Step 3: *Enable extension*

Edit your `php.ini` and load the `php_mssql` library and restart your Apache web server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Epel is installed. The second link is not accepted by my Centos "not an rpm package". I think mssql is enabled in my system. phpinfo() gives mssql by Freets library. Is that a good sign?

Comment: Oké. I will remove the current mssql library and search for the Remi extention.

Comment: Sorry, i've redacted my previous statement. I don't think it matters where you install the library from. Library version of FreeTDS is correct. I think the issue might be to do with the config file. Have you tried clearing CodeIgniter cache?

Comment: Codeigniter cache is empty. When i install freetds my codeigniter gives an database error and when i remove freetds codeigniter gives an blanc page. So i thin is helps. But on the internet many tutorials with freetds changes Linux config files with the server settings. But i like to do that in my codeigniter..

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.6tech.org/2013/01/centos-6-3-apache-2-2-15-mssql-2008-r2/

Comment: In this tuturial the server details are stored in de config file on Linux. But what is the function of the db file of Codeigniter in this case?

Comment: I am having this same issue. However your tutorial is no longer up and working. So can we get an answer to this?

Comment: I have added some extra info for you: Bill

Answer (score 0):

> Codeigniter_project\application\config\database.php

```
 $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'Admin@321',
    'database' => 'xxxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    //'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);


$db['posdb']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433';
//$db['posdb']['port'] = 1433; // or the port you configured on step 6
$db['posdb']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['posdb']['password'] = 'myself@123';
$db['posdb']['database'] = '
```

> Blockquote

new';

```
$db['posdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['posdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['posdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['posdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['posdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['posdb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['posdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['posdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['posdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['posdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['posdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Consider posdb be the second database which is going to connect with remote mssql at 2012

To get this in Controller is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Contrller_name extends CI_Controller{     

    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();     
      $this->load->model('my_model');
      $this->load->library('session');    
    }
    public function connet(){       
        $connnet =  $this->my_model->connet();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($connnet);
        //var_dump($connnet);
    }
}   
?>
```

> Now at model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_model extends CI_Model
{
     function __construct()
     {         
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->helper('date');
          $this->pos_db= $this->load->database('posdb', TRUE);  // loading secondary remote database 

     }
     function connet(){        
        $sql ="SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Party";
    $query = $this->pos_db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
     }

}?>
```

> This is worked for me most of times